# docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 default:latest fails for appsody quarkus stack

Tags: appsody

docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 default:latest fails for appsody quarkus stack. the image is tagged appsody-quarkus:latest

I tried

docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 appsody-quarkus:latest

$ docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 default:latest
Unable to find image 'default:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for default, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo, try appsody/quarkus

Comment: "docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 appsody-quarkus:latest" works.
"docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 default:latest" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That is a typo in the README.md for the stack.

You have it right with appsody-quarkus:latest

There is a PR for fixing the doc
https://github.com/appsody/stacks/pull/451